# How to Send Soap request to JAX-WS webservice from PHP?

Tags: java, php, soap

I'm trying to get XML request by using __getLastRequest() like below but failing, plz help

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
     xmlns:ord="http://medplus.com/orders">
     <soapenv:Header/>
     <soapenv:Body>
    <ord:getOrderDocuments>
        <request>
            <hl7Order>IvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGU+PnN0cmVhbQp4nbPbOQ. . . Base64-encoded content truncated
            </hl7Order>
            <orderSupportRequests>
                <requestType>ABN</requestType>
                <requestType>REQ</requestType>
            </orderSupportRequests>
        </request>
    </ord:getOrderDocuments>
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I send this SOAP request and can get its response using PHP?

Comment: I am writing soap client in php for a webservice written in JAX-WS framework. I want to call we service method from php soap client whose signature is as:Method Signature
OrderSupportServiceResponse getOrderDocuments(OrderSupportServiceRequest request)
throws SOAPException

Answer (score 0):

You can check documentation for PHP WSDL client here:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php

```
$service_url ="my url";
$client = new SoapClient($service_url,array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
    $response = $client->ord:getOrderDocuments(array (
        "hl7Order" => "IvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGU...",
        //..... other args
    ));

//fetch response        
$output =$response->return;
```